# Comparing Two Lists to Find Bigger List

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists and need to compare them by their largest element, if that is tied, their 2nd largest element, and if that is tied, 3rd largest etc iterating to the entire array.

For example:

```
list1= [0,2,3,6,12]
list2= [1,2,3,6,12]
list3= [1,4,5,8,12]
list4= [1,4,5,9,12]
```

So list4 > list3 > list2 > list1.

I wrote a function that accomplishes this:

```
def compare(x,y):
    if sorted(x)==sorted(y):
        return "Tie"
    for index in range(len(x)-1,-1,-1):
        if sorted(x)[index]>sorted(y)[index]:
            return x
        elif sorted(x)[index]<sorted(y)[index]:
            return y
```

I was wondering if there was a much neater and more efficient way of writing the function because it doesn't seem very Pythonic.

Edit: comparing lists by using "<" and ">" will sort the lists from the smallest index to largest index, not largest index to smallest index. Reversed would make ">" and "<" the simplest solutions.

Comment: Your text says you want to compare them by their largest element first, but your code doesn't do that, it compares by smallest element first. It just so happens that you've chosen an example where those two different sort orders have the same result.

Comment: Good catch- I think I can fix the error by reversing the index in range

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> list1= [0,2,3,6,12]
>>> list2= [1,2,3,6,12]
>>> list3= [1,4,5,8,12]
>>> list4= [1,4,5,9,12]
>>> def sort_lists_by_maxes(*lists):
    return sorted(lists, key=lambda x: sorted(x, reverse=True), reverse=True)

>>> sort_lists_by_maxes(list1, list2, list3, list4)
[[1, 4, 5, 9, 12], [1, 4, 5, 8, 12], [1, 2, 3, 6, 12], [0, 2, 3, 6, 12]]
```

The lists are compared by their individually sorted values, and you can feed as many lists as you would like into the function as arguments.

Comment: @wim The OP appears to want the lists in reverse order, with the lists with largest values first. Although the outer order is not explicitly referred to in the question, the example makes this clear, I think.

Answer (score 1):

sorted of sorted is good, but I'm partial to:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

list1 = [0, 2, 3, 6, 12]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 12]
list3 = [1, 4, 5, 8, 12]
list4 = [1, 4, 5, 9, 12]

metalist = [ list1, list2, list3, list4 ]

for sublist in metalist:
    sublist.sort(reverse=True)

metalist.sort(reverse=True)

print(metalist)
```

It should be faster and take less memory.  It's also more clear to novices.